# Import file from SQL server database using shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing an app using shiny which will import data from database (sql server) and displayed in main panel in shiny. Since the app will be dynamic in nature it will ask user for server details like server name, database name, user id….On entering those details and clicking ok button following error is displayed in rstudio console.

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server 
Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
Warning: Error in sqlQuery: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

Since error message said “file doesn’t exist or access denied” I designed an easy version of app wherein all details are hard coded like server name, database name, user id, password, file name and it worked perfectly fine and data gets loaded from database in shiny app. Following is the server code

```
output$display <- renderDataTable({
                  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=”my_server”;database=”database_name”;uid=”abc”;pwd=”123#')
                  e <- sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("Select * from ##file_name_in_sqlserver))
                  as.data.frame(e)})
```

The challenge is when I try to make it dynamic where users will input those credentials I am getting error. It seems I am pretty close but missing something very basic.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("fileinput"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons("filetype", "Select 2nd option",choices=c("csv file","From server")),

  #server selected and details entered 
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.filetype == 'From server'",
    textInput("text1", label = h5("Server Name"), value = ""),
    textInput("text2", label = h5("Database Name"), value = ""),
    textInput("text3", label = h5("User Id"), value = ""),
    textInput("text4", label = h5("password"), value = ""),
    textInput("text5", label = h5("File name"), value = ""),
    actionButton("ok","update")
  )
  ),
mainPanel(
  dataTableOutput("display")
))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# importing from database
data <- reactive({
if(input$filetype=="csv file"){      
}else if(input$filetype == "From server"){
  input$ok
  isolate({a <- input$text1
  b <- input$text2
  c <- input$text3
  d <- input$text4
  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=a;database=b;uid=c;pwd=d')
  e<-sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("Select * from input$text5"))
  databaseClose(dbhandle)
  as.data.frame(e)})
}else{
}})

# Display data
output$display <- renderDataTable({
data()})
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: RODBC uses ODBC connectors that you have to setup in your server machine (the one shiny is running). Try other package for SQL connections..

Comment: It seems that arguments of database connectors are not reactive and therefore not considering inputs passed by user.

Comment: Try this:

  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=a;database=b;uid=c;pwd=d', uid = c, pwd = d)

Comment: I did, Error says uid and pwd are unused arguments. They are used twice